# How do I get the next value from a javascript array to compare against the current value in a for loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a snippet of code that compares two dates and if they're the same it sets a boolean to true. I am getting an error on the line: `var nextFolioArrive = new Date(this.folios[i+1].folioDepart);`

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "folioDepart" from undefined. (line 50, file "propertyObject")
```

However it throws no error when I define:

```
var folioDepart = new Date(this.folios[i].folioDepart);
```

I was wondering if I can't "look ahead" in an array like that, not sure why it would be an issue.

```
  property.prototype.isTurn = function(){

    for (var i=0;i<this.folios.length;i++){

      var folioArrive = new Date(this.folios[i].folioArrive);
      var folioDepart = new Date(this.folios[i].folioDepart);

      var nextFolioArrive = new Date(this.folios[i+1].folioDepart);

      if(folioDepart == nextFolioArrive && folioArrive == TODAY){
        Logger.log("turn day: " +this.turnDay);
        return this.turnDay = true;
      }
      Logger.log("turn day: false" );
    }
  }
```

Here is all the code in the property object, I feel like I am making a silly syntax mistake or over looking something small.

```
var TODAY = new Date();
TODAY.setHours(0,0,0,0)

var propertyList = new Array();

function property(name,address) {

  //Default variables

  //Object variables
  this.name = name;
  this.address = address;
  this.workOrders = new Array();
  this.folios = new Array();
  this.GIH = false;
  this.turnDay = false;
  propertyList.push(this);  


  property.prototype.listArrivals = function(){
    Logger.log(this.name);
    for(var i=0;i<this.folios.length;i++){
      Logger.log(this.folios[i].folioID);
    }
  }
  property.prototype.listWorkorders = function(){
    Logger.log(this.name);
    for(var i=0;i<this.workOrders.length;i++){
      Logger.log(this.workOrders[i].workorderID);
    }
  }
  property.prototype.getGIH = function(){

     for (var i = 0;i<this.folios.length;i++){
       var folioArrive = new Date(this.folios[i].folioArrive);
       var folioDepart = new Date(this.folios[i].folioDepart);
       if(TODAY >= folioArrive && TODAY <= folioDepart && this.GIH == false){
         return this.GIH = true;
       }
     }
  }

  property.prototype.isTurn = function(){

    for (var i=0;i<this.folios.length;i++){

      var folioArrive = new Date(this.folios[i].folioArrive);
      var folioDepart = new Date(this.folios[i].folioDepart);

      var k = i+1;

      var nextFolioArrive = new Date(this.folios[k].folioDepart);

      if(folioDepart == nextFolioArrive && folioArrive == TODAY){
        Logger.log("turn day: " +this.turnDay);
        return this.turnDay = true;
      }
      Logger.log("turn day: false" );
    }
  }
}
```

I should have included my testing environment.

```
function myFunction() {

  function addDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result;
  }

  var tempPropertyList = [];
  var tempWorkOrderList = [];
  var tempFolioList = [];

  var i;
  var j;
  var k;

  var property1 = new property("property1","123 street");
  var property2 = new property("property2","123 ave");


//  folio(ID,type,propName,address,arrive,depart)
  var folio1 = new folio("303245","type","property1","123 street","03/14/2019", "03/30/2019");
  var folio2 = new folio("303243","type","property2","123 ave","03/26/2019", "03/30/2019");
  var folio3 = new folio("303244","type","property1","123 street","03/30/2019", "04/10/2019");
  var folio4 = new folio("303246","type","property2","123 ave","03/20/2019", "03/25/2019");
  var folio5 = new folio("303247","type","property1","123 street","03/01/2019", "03/14/2019"); 

//workOrder(ID,propName,type,description,due,notes) {  

  var wo1 = new workOrder("12","property1","Maint","workOrder1","03/14/2019","");
  var wo2 = new workOrder("13","property2","Maint","workOrder2","03/20/2019","");
  var wo3 = new workOrder("14","property1","Maint","workOrder3","03/19/2019","");
  var wo4 = new workOrder("15","property1","Maint","workOrder4","02/02/2019","");
  var wo5 = new workOrder("16","property2","Maint","workOrder5","03/14/2019","");
  var wo6 = new workOrder("17","property2","Maint","workOrder6","03/14/2019","");
  var wo7 = new workOrder("18","property1","Maint","workOrder7","03/15/2019","");
  var wo8 = new workOrder("19","property1","Maint","workOrder8","03/16/2019","");
  var wo9 = new workOrder("10","property2","Maint","workOrder9","04/01/2019","");
  var wo10 = new workOrder("11","property2","Maint","workOrder10","05/05/2019","");

  //push objects to arrays

  tempWorkOrderList.push(wo1,wo2,wo3,wo4,wo5,wo6,wo7,wo8,wo9,wo10);
  tempFolioList.push(folio1,folio5,folio2,folio3,folio4);
  tempPropertyList.push(property1,property2);

  for (i=0;i<tempPropertyList.length;i++){
    tempPropertyList[i].isTurn();

    for (j=0;j<tempWorkOrderList.length;j++){
      if (tempWorkOrderList[j].workorderProperty == tempPropertyList[i].name){
        tempPropertyList[i].workOrders.push(tempWorkOrderList[j]);
      }
    }
    for (k=0;k<tempFolioList.length;k++){
      if(tempFolioList[k].folioProperty == tempPropertyList[i].name){
        tempPropertyList[i].folios.push(tempFolioList[k]);
      }
    }
    tempPropertyList[i].isTurn();
  }

}
```

Comment: Consider when you're on the final iteration of your loop, that is, `i = array.length - 1`. What does `array[i+1]` point to in that case?

Comment: Change for (var i=0;i<this.folios.length;i++) to for (var i=0;i<this.folios.length-1;i++)

Answer (score 0):

Check the existance of the object first before using its property

```
property.prototype.isTurn = function(){

    for (var i=0;i<this.folios.length;i++){

      var folioArrive = new Date(this.folios[i].folioArrive);
      var folioDepart = new Date(this.folios[i].folioDepart);
      // check next folio
      if (typeof this.folios[i+1] != 'undefined') {
         var nextFolioArrive = new Date(this.folios[i+1].folioDepart);

         if(folioDepart == nextFolioArrive && folioArrive == TODAY){
           Logger.log("turn day: " +this.turnDay);
           return this.turnDay = true;
         }
         Logger.log("turn day: false" );
      } 
    }
  }
```